# Displaying pdf file as embedded from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am very new to this field. I am sorry if this is stupid.

I have a HttpServlet code as follow:

```
@WebServlet("file")
public class FileResource extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7698183933607633414L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

        resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");

        File file = new File("/home/nabin/12403.pdf");
        long fileSize = file.length();
        resp.setContentLengthLong(fileSize);

        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/nabin/12403.pdf"));
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());

            for (;;) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int n = in.read(buffer);
                if (n == -1)
                    break;
                out.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a xhtml file where I want to display that pdf file. I want to display it as embedded.

```
<embed src="../questions/#{FileResource.get}.pdf" width="105%"
                            height="825px" />
```

Right now I can access the pdf file using `localhost:8080/myapp/file`
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now being able to see the response inside iframe.

Also now I am sending request query as following:

```
<iframe src="/myapp/file?id=#{param.id}"/>
```

And in servlet class, I am retrieving the id using `getParameter("id");` method

Answer (score 1):

**pdf.js** can be used to display pdf file 
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: And how is this js project relevant to java-ee? Should I integrate?

Comment: I think you need to add that library ,I have used iText library for pdf 
you can try that as well,hope it helps

Comment: I think it works good.